# How to get ID from another model in django?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models that it must be input to database in same time by submit button in my template.

this is my first model

```
class DataPribadiSiswa(models.Model):
   SiswaID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   WaliKelasID=models.CharField(max_length=5,blank=True,null=True)
   SiswaNIS = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

second model

```
class RiwayatSekolah(models.Model):
   SekolahID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   SiswaID_FK=models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True,null=True)
```

and this is my view.py

```
def tambah_siswa(request):
   form = datasiswa(request.POST)
   form2 = riwayatsekolah(request.POST)
   if request.method == 'POST':
       if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
           form.save()
           form2.save()
           return redirect('index')
   else:
       form = datasiswa()
       form2 = riwayatsekolah()
   return render(request, 'siswa/tambah_siswa.html', {'form': form, 'form2': form2})
```

how to insert `SiswaID` from`DataPribadiSiswa` to `SiswaID_FK` in `RiwayatSekolah` at same time where all form is blank?

Comment: u do not have a foreign key field?

Comment: Why is `SiswaID_FK` is a `CharField` and why don't you simply use a `ForeignKey`? Is this a legacy database?

Comment: Use a `ForeignKey` instead of a `CharField`.

Comment: I have tried to use foreignkey, but  SiswaID_FK wouldn't get SiswaID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ForeignKey field.

```
class RiwayatSekolah(models.Model):
    SekolahID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    SiswaID_FK=models.ForeignKey(DataPribadiSiswa)
```

Now in view you can try to save Siswa instance first and then to add it into Sekolah instance:

```
def tambah_siswa(request):
    form = datasiswa(request.POST)
    form2 = riwayatsekolah(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            siiswa_instance = form.save()
            Sekolah_instance = form2.save(commit=False)
            Sekolah_instance.SiswaID_FK = siiswa_instance
            Sekolah_instance.save()
```